# Octave Installation and package inclusion doubts

Tags: c++, octave

I'm listing the question I had already asked on Octave help mailing list, hoping that I'll get an answer here.

I'm building an application that calls Octave core and package functions from c++ code.

1. I have built Octave using `./configure --without-java --disable-docs --without-opengl --without-qt`

The lib folder is 414 MB in size. Are there any other options that I can use to reduce the size of the lib folder?

2. I've placed the Octave include and lib folders under the following path `/path_to_application/thirdparty/linux/include` and `/path_to_application/thirdparty/linux/lib`

I'm able to call the Octave core functions from the c++ code. How do I install the packages and place them under `thirdparty` folder such that the c++ code can also call the package functions. Is there any generic prefix I can set?

This application will be distributed among many users. The application should be able to call the package functions on any system without any issues regarding the path.

Comment: Can you please add the link to your question on the mailinglist? For example via nabble

Comment: Here's the link- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2017-01/msg00092.html

Comment: Can you please also create a link to your current sourcecode?

Comment: The source code is available here- https://github.com/shamikam/FOSSEE_Scilab_Octave_Interface_Toolbox

The Octave files are in thirdparty folder.